# How do I configure apache to only show if the visitor's IP is a specified one?

Tags: apache-2.2

I only want to show the content for myself, how do I configure the apache?

I'm using proxy to visit the site.

I can't do it with iptables for priviledge reasons..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have access permission on the proxy? If so, enable `X-FORWARDED-FOR` and configure Apache like belows:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For ^your\.real\.IP\.address let_me_in
Order allow,deny
allow from env=let_me_in
ErrorDocument 403 http://google.com
```

---

> how can I allow access only when there's a flat=1 in the querystring?

You can use mod_rewrite to do this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*)flat=1(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: As mentioned in the comments on my answer, I don't like this solution.  `X-Forwarded-For` is easily spoofable and is provided for informational needs only.  Using it for access control is a _very bad thing™_.  (Though this is more elegant than the mod_rewrite hackery I was thinking of, so +1)

Comment: I just found `X-Forwarded-For` is not supported by my proxy server,how can I allow access only when there's a `flat=1` in the querystring?

Comment: I have no `index.php` in my web site, and it seems it's not doing the logic of `allow/deny` ...

Comment: Use negative matching: if the request not including `flat=1`, it will be redirect to forbidden page (403) - `F` flag.

Comment: What does NC mean here?

Comment: `NC` means No Case: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: What does `-` mean in `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,NC]`?

Comment: It means that no substitution, leaving original URL untouched.

Answer (score 4):

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from x.x.x.x
```

This will prevent access from all addresses other than the one specified.  Place it in your `<VirtualHost>` block, or `.htaccess` file, or a `<Directory>` or `<Location>` block - whatever fits your needs.

Comment: Will it work when using proxy?

Comment: @linux You'll need to specify the proxy's address to allow the proxy.  If that's providing too much access, then look into password protection with basic auth at the link in @O G's answer.

Comment: That's not what I want then,it should only allow my real IP to visit even if I'm using proxy...In PHP,it can be get by `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`

Comment: @linux Only if your proxy supports the `X-Forwarded-For` header.  If that header's in place, then you can potentially use it control access via `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-For}`, but I will strongly recommend against using an easily spoofable header as an access control.

Answer (score 2):

See this link : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html - and use any of the two methods you would like. Or even both.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are behind a proxy it may be easier to just password protect your site.

Create a file called `.htaccess` in your `DocumentRoot` directory then add this (if it already exists then just add to it)

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthName "Secret Squirrel"
AuthType Basic
Require Valid-User
```

change /path/to above to something that suits you.

then create the file /path/to/.htpasswd and add a username and password

```
htpasswd -c /path/to/.htpasswd user
```

this will create the file and add a username `user` and ask for the password. Now your website is password protected.